# Implementing a generic map with java

Tags: java

I understood that you can pass pretty much anything to a method with an object.  I am trying to write an assert function that checks whether two maps are equal.  I can't just use map1.equals(map2) because even if they have all the same keys and values, they might be in a different order.  So I wanted to go througheach key in the first map and get its value and compare it to the value for that key in the second map.  And I wanted to do it generically.  So I wrote this (which is sort of a stub to demonstrate my question.  I will do more null checking, etc):

```
public void assertMapEquals( Map<Object, Object> f, Map<Object, Object> l) {

    // This will do null checks, don't worry
    for ( Entry<Object, Object> ent : f.entrySet()) {       
        if (f.size() != l.size()) {
            throw new AssertionError ("size mismatch");
        }       
        Object k = ent.getKey();
        Object e = ent.getValue();
        Object a = l.get(k);        
        if (!e.equals(a)) {
            throw new AssertionError( "unequal");
        }       
    }
}
```

Then I try to call it with two String maps:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException {

    Map<String,String> m1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,String> m2 = new HashMap<>();
    // Data will get filled in later
    assertMapEquals(m1, m2);
    // ...
 }
```

but Eclipse is giving me the following error on the call:

> The method assertMapEquals(Map, Map) in
>   the type MyMain1 is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Map, Map)

Aren't strings objects, so why won't this work, and what should I do?  This question can apply to any example of this sort, not just comparing two maps.

An additional question I would have is is there a better way I can do this where it compares but does not care about the order?

Comment: Why don't you use `assertMapEquals(Map<String,String>, Map<String,String>)` ?

Comment: That is what I changed it to, but it is conceiveable I would want to call it sometimes with other types of maps.

Comment: Ordering is only guaranteed if you are using `TreeMap`. Any other `Map` does not preserve ordering of the keys

Comment: why do you check for `f.size() != l.size()` on each iteration? this check should be done outside the foreach.

Comment: I don't follow your reason for not using `AbstractMap.equals()`. From the JavaDoc for `AbstractMap` - "More formally, two maps m1 and m2 represent the same mappings if m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet())". That should be order independent and sounds exactly like what you're trying to implement.

Comment: No reason.  I wasn't aware of it ;-)

Comment: tucuxi, the check is done outside the iteration

Comment: OK I misunderstood what you meant about AbstractMap.equals().  I did try it but though the keys and values were the same, they were in a different order so it gave me an error.

Comment: @Tony please note that if you want to compare order of keys in their natural order you need to use implementation of `SortedMap`, if you want to compare order of keys by the order in which keys were inserted you should use `LinkedHashMap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use generic method paramethized by `<?, ?>` *(not `<K, V>`, because as mentioned in comments they may be of different type and still equal, e. g. `Map<String, String>` vs `Map<Object, Object>`)*:

```
public static void assertMapEquals(Map<?, ?> f, Map<?, ?> l) {
    if (f == null || l == null)
         throw new NullPointerException();
    if (f.size() != l.size()) 
            throw new AssertionError ("size mismatch");
    for (Entry<?, ?> ent : f.entrySet()) {            
        Object k = ent.getKey();
        Object e = ent.getValue();
        Object a = l.get(k);        
        if (!Objects.equals(e, a))      // handle null values
            throw new AssertionError("unequal");
    }
}
```

The other approach will be just directly compare maps:

```
public static void assertMapEquals(Map<?, ?> f, Map<?, ?> l) {
     if (f == null || l == null)
         throw new NullPointerException();
     if (f.size() != l.size())
         throw new AssertionError("size mismatch");
     if (!f.equals(l))
         throw new AssertionError("unequal contents");
}
```

By contract, `Map#equals(Object o)` returns true iff `o` is `Map` which has equal contents.